# Drop duplicate foreign keys with SQLAlchemy Migrate

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

By mistake I added two foreign keys referring to the same table and column. The `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_a` look like:

```
table_a | CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
`id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`fk` int(11) default NULL,
`created_at` datetime default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
KEY `fk` (`fk`),
CONSTRAINT `table_a_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk`) REFERENCES `table_b` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `table_a_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`fk`) REFERENCES `table_b` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

My only solution at this point is to iterate over all the keys/constraints on the column and remove them followed by adding the cascade key one more time.

Is there a way to remove only the non-cascade constraint using [SQLAlchemy Migrate](http://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
cons = ForeignKeyConstraint(columns=[table.c.fk],
                            refolumns=[table_b.c.id],
                            name="table_a_ibfk_1")
cons.drop(engine=migrate_engine)
```